# Angular 2, Webpack, Express, HMR

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I am developing my Angular 2 application using Webpack and HMR. At this stage there is a static application with no interaction with the backend. All data is static dummy data.

I am at the point where it is time to start adding the express/node backend so I can interact with the database however I don't want to lose the HMR functionality.

Is it possible to set this up so that:

1. I can serve the Angular 2 app from Node using express and jade.
2. I make a change to my Angular 2 app and HMR kicks in and hot swaps the code into my browser window.

Currently my webpack setup is split into three files (dev, prod, common). I've included below the dev and common files as they are most relevant.

**Startup command**

```
webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress --port 8080
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'styles': './src/styles/main.scss',
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'

  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', 'scss']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      }
      ,
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }

    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'styles']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Raceloop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/button-toggle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/grid-list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/menu": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/progress-bar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/slide-toggle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/slider": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/tabs": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/tooltip": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@ngrx/core": "1.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "2.1.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "angular2-apollo": "^0.4.5",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.14",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "typed-immutable-record": "0.0.5",
    "zone.js": "0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.28",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^3.9.3",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "0.8.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "2.1.0-dev.20160903",
    "typings": "1.3.3",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.21",
    "webpack-dashboard": "0.1.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.3",
    "webpack-merge": "0.14.1",
    "worker-loader": "0.7.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **webpack-hot-middleware** plugin it is actually quite straight forward.

**webpack.express.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var hotMiddlewareScript = 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000&reload=true';

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    // Include the hot middleware with each entry point
    entry: {
        // Add the client which connects to our middleware
        'styles': ['../src/styles/main.scss', hotMiddlewareScript],
        'polyfills': ['../src/app/polyfills.ts', hotMiddlewareScript],
        'vendor': ['../src/app/vendor.ts', hotMiddlewareScript],
        'manager': ['../src/app/main-manager.ts', hotMiddlewareScript],
        'authenticator': ['../src/app/main-authenticator.ts', hotMiddlewareScript]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', 'scss']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
            }

        ]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['mainapp', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'styles']
        }),

        //new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        //    template: '../src/index.html'
        //}),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
};
```

**Server.Js**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />

let http = require('http');
let express = require('express');
let morgan = require('morgan');


let app = express();
app.use(morgan('short'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// ************************************
// This is the real meat of the example
// ************************************
(function() {

    let webpack = require('webpack');
    let webpackDevMiddleWare = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
    let webpackHotMiddleWare = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

    // Step 1: Create & configure a webpack compiler
    let webpackConfig = require(process.env.WEBPACK_CONFIG ? process.env.WEBPACK_CONFIG : '../webpack.config');
    let compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    // Step 2: Attach the dev middleware to the compiler & the server
    app.use(webpackDevMiddleWare(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
    }));

    // Step 3: Attach the hot middleware to the compiler & the server
    app.use(webpackHotMiddleWare(compiler, {
        log: console.log,
        path: '/__webpack_hmr',
        heartbeat: 10 * 1000
        }));
})();

// Do anything you like with the rest of your express application.

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index-manager.html');
});
app.get("/multientry", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index-multientry.html');
});

if (require.main === module) {
    let server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 4200, function() {
        console.log("Listening on %j", server.address());
    });
}
```